# Java how to parse a double value from received UDP bytes?

Tags: java, byte

```
int port = 18000;
DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
byte[] receiveData = new byte[8];

System.out.println("Server Listing on Port: "+port);
String x;

while (true){
  DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
  serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
```

?? Double x = new Doulbe.parseBytes(recievedPacket)

Comment: Try with `DoubleBuffer`.

Comment: I love your implementation. Using the same thing myself :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html%3a)

```
Double x = ByteBuffer.wrap(receiveData).getDouble();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `java.nio.ByteBuffer`

Something like:

```
private static ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);    

public static byte[] encodeDouble(double x) {
    buffer.clear();
    buffer.putDouble(0, x);
    return buffer.array();
}

public static double decodeDouble(byte[] bytes) {
    buffer.clear();
    buffer.put(bytes);
    buffer.flip(); 
    return buffer.getDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ByteBuffer.wrap(receiveData.getData()).getDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.io.DataInputStream.readDouble()
```