# Java How to parse UTC from Sint64 in udp packet

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, utc

I have a UDP packet coming in that holds a UTC in form of Sint64. How to turn this into a UTC time?

Sint64 = 8 bytes
i have an allocated byte array of 8 below. this is the only thing coming into 'receivedData' byte array

```
    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(18000);
    byte[] receiveData = new byte[8];

    while (true)
    {
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
        serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);

       //not sure how I should be reading the raw binary data back into UTC object

    }
```

Comment: Much the same way as any of the other questions that you've asked on the same topic. Like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071070/java-how-to-parse-a-double-value-from-received-udp-bytes). The only difference here is what the 64-bit value in the packet actually *means* (ie, is it a count of milliseconds?), and whatever documentation you have should explain that.

Comment: Incidentally, it would be much better for you if you described the entire packet format. Then someone could give you a simple answer of how to wrap an arbitrary-size `byte[]` in a `ByteBuffer` and use getters to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to convert the byte array into a `long` (signed integer of 64 bit):

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(receiveData);
long utcTime = buf.getLong();
```

This code assumes that the 64-bit value is stored in the same byte order (little endian vs. big endian) that the processor uses for running your application.

You don't specify what exactly the 64-bit value is. I'll assume it's the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 0:00 UTC.

So to construct a date, use this code:

```
Date dateTime = new Date(utcTime);
```

If you have a different zero point or a different unit, you'll need to adapt it accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

UDP uses network byte order which is Big Endian. x86 uses little endian, so the bytebuff example above will fail on x86, since it does not know that the long comes from the net.

```
        return (((long)readBuffer[0] << 56) +
                ((long)(readBuffer[1] & 255) << 48) +
                ((long)(readBuffer[2] & 255) << 40) +
                ((long)(readBuffer[3] & 255) << 32) +
                ((long)(readBuffer[4] & 255) << 24) +
                ((readBuffer[5] & 255) << 16) +
                ((readBuffer[6] & 255) <<  8) +
                ((readBuffer[7] & 255) <<  0));
```

or

```
return (((long)in.read() << 56) +
                ((long)(in.read() & 255) << 48) +
                ((long)(in.read() & 255) << 40) +
                ((long)(in.read() & 255) << 32) +
                ((long)(in.read() & 255) << 24) +
                ((in.read() & 255) << 16) +
                ((in.read() & 255) <<  8) +
                ((in.read() & 255) <<  0));
```

should do the trick (read Big Endian from buffer/stream).

Comment: ByteBuffers are Big Endian by default.